# how can i push message between server and client in namedPipeWrapper?

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I wrote the client and server side based on the documentation [Named Pipe Wrapper](https://github.com/acdvorak/named-pipe-wrapper), but unfortunately only server.ClientConnected runs and server.ClientMessage and client.ServerMessage do not run. How can I push a message from the client to the server And vice versa?

model :

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Request { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

client side :

```
var client = new NamedPipeClient<SomeClass>("MyServerPipe");

        client.ServerMessage += delegate (NamedPipeConnection<SomeClass, SomeClass> conn, SomeClass message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response);
        };

        // Start up the client asynchronously and connect to the specified server pipe.
        // This method will return immediately while the client runs in a separate background thread.
        client.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

server side:

```
 var server = new NamedPipeServer<SomeClass>("MyServerPipe");

        server.ClientConnected += delegate (NamedPipeConnection<SomeClass, SomeClass> conn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} is now connected!", conn.Id);
            conn.PushMessage(new SomeClass { Response= "Welcome!" });
        };

        server.ClientMessage += delegate (NamedPipeConnection<SomeClass, SomeClass> conn, SomeClass message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} says: {1}", conn.Id, message.Request);
        };

        // Start up the server asynchronously and begin listening for connections.
        // This method will return immediately while the server runs in a separate background thread.
        server.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://github.com/acdvorak/named-pipe-wrapper)

To test the performance of the pipe, it is better that you convert the `ExampleCLI` project into two client and server projects and move the SomeClass model into a new class library. Your problem occurs when the model is serializable. That is why the `server.ClientMessage`, and `client.ServerMessage` are not called.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The main problem in serializing was in different projects, which was solved when I took the model into a class library.